# relationship laravel empty result

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I´m traying create relation ship in my model user-roles.

Firt i have to say that i´m using `Bouncer` library to use permission and roles.

I have my model User with this realation:

```
public function roles()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\AssignedRoles', 'entity_id');
}
```

and my model AssignedRole:

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'id', 'entity_id');
}
```

and

```
public function roleName()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Role', 'id', 'role_id');
}
```

in my controller i´m trayin return all role that it has one User, using this:

```
$employee = User::with('roles')->get();
```

but return this:

```
Array([roles] => )
```

what i´m doing wrong?

I need create user list with his roles.

Thanks for read and sorry for my english